# Splunkbase modular inputs customized UI

Tags: splunk

I've seen number of resources that described how to create customized UI for modular inputs but this customization is limited to configuration of Manager XML file (http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.6.1/AdvancedDev/ModInputsCustomizeUI). In this configuration customer will have possibility to specify only some static configs.

We'd like to build highly customised UI for "modular inputs" hence we should call external REST services to help customers to specify correct values for "modular inputs". Like present drop down with options and other stuff.

Is there're any ways to create such customized UI for modular inputs ? Any good references to follow ?

Comment: You can create any sort of interface for any sort of modular input - for example, create a 'normal' app view (which you can completely customize) and have your modinput as the backend (you can pipe anything to it) - then your modinput can grab the `session_key` from STDIN and access the [Splunk API](http://dev.splunk.com/restapi) directly to create any sort of input you want. You'd also have better luck with specific questions @ [answers.splunk.com](https://answers.splunk.com/).

Comment: "have your modinput as the backend (you can pipe anything to it" Could you please share some link that explains how to connect "Custom UI" to "custom backend" ?

Comment: Check the [Write Custom Search Commands ](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.6.1/Search/Aboutcustomsearchcommands) chapter. While intended for searching it doesn't really stop you from calling your script with any parameters disguised as a search.